# facebook 'like' onload callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I am looking for a way to know when the facebook like button has finished loading, so I can resize the parent element using javascript.

Any idea if such an event is fired?

Comment: http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:like does this help at all ?

Answer (score 1):

FB.init usually starts after plugin objects are loaded. Did you try that?